# Close DownloadFileAsync thread vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an ftp host where i need to download and unzip a zip file. This is an example of my current code. When i try to run the unzip script i get the exception that the file is still being used in another process. How do i close the webclient downloadfileasync correctly?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
    Private wc As New WebClient()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        wc = New WebClient()

        AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, Sub(s As Object, ByVal e1 As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
                                                Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() ProgressBar1.Value = e1.ProgressPercentage))
                                            End Sub

        AddHandler wc.DownloadFileCompleted, Sub(s As Object, e1 As ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Complete")
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(downloadPath & DagensXML, downloadPath)

                                            End Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("ftp://user:pass@0.0.0.0/ESStatistikListeModtag/ESStatistikListeModtag-20160327-094743.zip"), "C:\XML\ESStatistikListeModtag-20160327-094743.zip")
    End Sub
End Class
```